How to use SMS API of Australia region for sending SMS with an Australian Number?
I am trying to use Australia Region API for SMS sending, But i am not able to use it i'm getting a 401 error code.
Let me know, How can i make Australia region sms sending Api Active by default it's US Region active


is it because of not availability ?

Please let me know as soon as possible!
Thanks
i tried with US Region API and it's working for that with Australian Number, but i want to use Australia Region API with Australian Number.
Let me know, How can i make Australia region sms sending Api Active by default it's US Region active 

is it because of not availability ?


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I'm afraid your assumption is right. This service is, as of now, not available in the AU1 region.
You can check this resource to check if this feature is available at a later point in time.
